# How do I choose the place the animation happens from using AnimatedVisibility in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to reveal a Card using AnimatedVisibility:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = isVisible.value,
    enter = expandIn(expandFrom = Alignment.TopEnd),
    exit = shrinkOut(shrinkTowards = Alignment.TopEnd)
) {
      Card(...) { ... }
}
```

(Also the card is constrained to the top-end corner of another view, but I don't think it should matter, since that view is static.)

It doesn't work as I expected. It still animates from the top left corner. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expandIn` animation does not control where the animation starts. The `expandFrom` parameter controls which part of your `Cart` appears first.

To control the start point of the animation, you can use `slideIn`. You can also combine them with `+`. You can read more about animations in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#high-level-apis), there are pretty good examples of all animations available there.

```
slideIn(initialOffset = { IntRect(offset = IntOffset.Zero, size = it).topRight} )
```